# How to access Object of Key in NSDictionary with NSNumber instead of NSString in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a **`NSDictionary`** and **`Int`** Variable :

```
mainDic = @{@1:@"1.jpg",@2:@"2.jpg"};
indexpath.row = 2;
```

I want to access to object for value 2 using **`indexpath.row`** like this :

```
cell.pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:mainDic[indexpath.row]];
```

But it doesn't work. ...

Comment: You dictionary is wrong I guess. Keys and values are are reversed. Also `[indexpath.row]` is an `NSUInteger` (a primitive), not an object, so it can't be a key. If it was an array, it could have work. Clearly, who created `mainDict`? And any reason why using dictionary instead of array (which are queried by index instead of keys)?

Comment: i think you should hard code dictionary like : `@{ key : value, key : value };` . please double check your input

Comment: I think you need to take a break, and look into the implementation of dictionary literal. I believe you are confused with NSDictionary's `ObjectWithKeys`

Comment: I get a NSDictionary from my API so I should use it as NSDictionary, but it is possible to use NSNumber as key in NSDictionary @Larme

Comment: I know it’s possible but in your current it’s not compilable as such

Comment: Don't worry, I know that `[UIImage imageNamed:@(mainDic[indexpath.row])];` would have fixed it. But when I wrote my first comment your dictionary wasn't the same. And I just explained the issues.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks for help. @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainDic = @{@1:@"1.jpg",@2:@"2.jpg"};` uses NSNumbers for keys in this dictionary.

@1 creates a `NSNumber`, its just a shortcut for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`.
so your Dictionary looks like this: `NSDictionary <NSNumber *, NSString *> *mainDic;`.

The row property of NSIndexPath is a readonly integer.
You try to access your NSDictionary with an integer and not with NSNumber as key, the right call should be:

```
NSNumber *row = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexpath.row];
cell.pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:mainDic[row]];
```

But I would just use an array, its way simpler to access the images from it.

```
NSArray *images = @[@"1.jpg",
                    @"2.jpg",
                    @"3.jpg"];
cell.pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:images[indexpath.row]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your key should be in the left side, not in right. And also there is typo, I think: @"2,jpg". But should be @"2.jpg".
But in general use an array instead of NSDictionary for this. Because Integer can't be a key, as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Check your input dictionary. You could entered wrong image name. Replace it with:

```
mainDic = @{@"1" : @"1.jpg", @"2" :@"2.jpg"};
cell.pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[mainDic valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexpath.row]]];
```